# Prove that the Moore plane is regular?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that the topology on the upper half of the plane generated by the basis given by open balls $B((x,y), r)$ where $r \le y$ and $B((x,y), r) \cup  \{ (x,0) \} $ where $r=y$ is regular. Here is what I have so far. Consider a closed set $A$ which is the complement of the union of several open sets in this topology. Then a point $p$ not in $A$ must be in one of those open sets. How do I show that $A$ is a subset of an open set disjoint from that open set?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the base that you described; it suffices to show that if $p\in B\in\mathscr{B}$, then there is a basic open nbhd of $p$ whose closure is contained in $B$.

I’ll write $\operatorname{cl}_MA$ for the closure of $A$ in the topology of the Moore plane, and $\overline{B}(p,\epsilon)$ for the closed ball of radius $\epsilon$ and centre $p$ in the open upper half-plane, i.e., the set of points whose distance from $p$ is at most $\epsilon$.

- If $y>r$, $\operatorname{cl}_MB(\langle x,y\rangle,r)=\overline{B}(\langle x,y\rangle,r)$.
- $\operatorname{cl}_MB(\langle x,y\rangle,y)=\overline{B}(\langle x,y\rangle)\cup\{\langle x,0\rangle\}$.
- $\operatorname{cl}_M\big(B(\langle x,y\rangle,y)\cup\{\langle x,0\rangle\}\big)=\overline{B}(\langle x,y\rangle)\cup\{\langle x,0\rangle\}$.

Once you verify these, it’s not too hard to use them and the regularity of the Euclidean topology to show the characterization of regularity that I gave in the first paragraph.

Comment: in second bullet point, $\overline{B}(\langle x,y\rangle)$ already contains point $(x,0)$, so why to mention it separately. Am I wrong? Or you wrote it just for more clarity.