# Find a continuous function from Moore plane to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Find a continuous function from the [Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) to $\mathbb{R}$ like $f$,such that $f(o) = 1$ and $f(X) = 0$ where $o$ denotes the origin and $X$ denotes the $x$-axis without origin.

My attempt: Based on the definition of completely regular spaces, this question is relative to that. I define $f$ in a way that $f(p) = 1/2$ where $p$ is a point with positive $y$-coordinate, unfortunately this function is not continuous.

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you already know that the space is completely regular. So all you need to prove is that $X$ is closed in it. Because then it is a simple matter of applying the definition of being completely regular to $(0,0)$ and $X$.

So why is $X$ closed? The simplest way is to show that its complement $X^c$ is open. If $(x,y)$ is such that $y>0$ then consdier $B((x,y),y/2)$ which is an open (euclidean) ball around $(x,y)$ of radius $y/2$. Then every element in $B((x,y),y/2)$ also has second coordinate greater than $0$. Which means that $B((x,y),y/2)\subseteq X^c$. And so every element with positive coordinate is contained in $X^c$ together with a small enough neighbourhood.

So the only point left is $(0,0)\in X^c$. But by the definition of Moore space, it has an open neighbourhood in the form of say $B((0,1),1)\cup\{(0,0)\}$. And this is a subset of $X^c$ as well.

All in all, $X^c$ is open and thus $X$ is closed.

And to see why Moore plane is regular, you can have a look here: [Prove that the Moore plane is regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511615/prove-that-the-moore-plane-is-regular)

Comment: Where can I see an appropriate proof of completely regularity?

Comment: @porseshgar in the link in my answer?